# Linking external data back to the blender file after moving

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, video-sequence-editor, blend-files, file-browser

I want a friend to render my 6400 frame short film I made on blender... And it has a lot of image textures for materials... I have all the images, music, and pretty much everything that is in the animation in one folder, including the actual blender file... But it seems the destination of the files will change because the folder would be installed on his computer and he would have to go and change all the matierial image texture file destinations to the same folder on his disk... Is there a way where he can just link up to all of the files without the hassle? Thanks

Comment: What happens if you copy your folder to a USB stick or SD card, and load your blend file? If you can load it from there you friend should be able to load it from there,too.

Comment: @RayMairlot  Though the answer to that question may address this users question that question is asking an entirely separate thing, transferring an *already packed* file between OS.  See [this meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question).

Comment: @PGmath I understand your point and I have quoted that meta post to many other people. To me the difference between the questions is a bit more subtle, but I can see that that the OP of the other question was a step further than this OP as they had already packed the blend.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! Both are great answers!

Answer (score 1):

You could pack the Blender file before giving it away.  Packing basically copies all the external files which the .blend file refers into into the .blend itself.  To pack external files go to *file* > *external data* > *pack all into .blend.*

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir... It worked... But what if I had images in blender and I wanted to pack them?

Comment: I meant if I added images in the video sequence editor... Because they weren't there when I packed it and moved it... I'm sorry

Comment: @Noah  Once you have packed the file, every time you save it it will pack any new external data you have added since the last pack.  When you save it should give you a message in the info bar that tells you how many new files have been packed.