# Why does my Fire animation not render?

Tags: rendering

I have made a animation of a spinning planet with an asteriod flameing up while going through the atmosphere. Everything is made in Blender Internal Rendering (version 2.76). However, I only get a few very strange looking purple sparks when rendering. In the viewport the animation works fine.

As far as I know my settings are correct, so I don´t know where to look for an error. I have of course gone through similar questions here, but all existing suggestions do not help.

You can also access the blender file with all textures and pictures via below link:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/uytfziny4tabwfv/World_ANI13.blend

The file size is 40mb.

You see 10 different screen-shots of my blender setttings via this link:

http://www.mediafire.com/view/tldmkymgmjkpn1k/ScreenShots.docx

I would really appreciate if if someone more skilled than me can try to find the error, as I am stuck.

Thanks,
Oscar

Comment: A screenshot of your material and fire settings and the output would be great.

Comment: Sure, I will try to add some screenshots of the various settings.

Comment: Instead of zipping and renaming files, just pack the images into the .blend file. read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36958/1853

Comment: @cegaton, thanks: I did not know that. However, now when I did that the file size is 41mb, so I can´t use pasteall to upload, as the size limit is 30mb. Do you know another file share site to use?

Comment: @NOVICEINDISGUISE. I am not able to upload more than two screen-shots here. So I have instead uploaded 10 different screenshots of my blender settings in a word doc to mediafire: http://www.mediafire.com/view/tldmkymgmjkpn1k/ScreenShots.docx.
I really would appreciate if you could have a look. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the .blend and rendered it with my rendering device set to CPU. It worked perfectly, but after I toggled it to GPU Compute, I got the same problem.

Maybe you should try turning your rendering device to CPU instead of GPU Compute? Not sure if it's already set to CPU.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying. I am realy glad that you got it to work. Then there is hope. But I tried to render with CPU, but still I get the same result. So there must be something else wrong? Did you chance anything else?

Comment: No nothing. Sorry.

Comment: sorry to keep asking you, but I am desperate to find a solution. What do you mean by you were able to render it? Was it showing the asteriod with actual fire around coming into the atmosphere at frame 2260 to 2600? And not just some stange looking purple spots around the astroide?

Comment: I redid the animation starting from an a old blend file which did not contain the fire animation. For some reason which I can´t explain the fire animation now renders. Anyway, the important thing is, that it is now working!

Comment: Glad to hear! Was probably some setting that was incorrect. Happy blending!